# Como compilar todos arquivos *.c e depois fazer um .so usando make?

Tags: c, makefile, make

Existe alguma maneira de criar todos os $(OBJ) de uma forma mais "eficiente" ao invés de criar uma entrada para cada um?

Meu makefile está assim:

```
all: lib.so
a.o: a.c a.h
    cc -fPIC -Wall -Wextra a.c -c
b.o: b.c b.h
    cc -fPIC -Wall -Wextra b.c -c
lib.so: a.o b.o
    cc -shared a.o b.o -o $@
```

Porém gostaria de algo assim, precisando apenas adicionar os arquivos em $(OBJ) $(SRC) e $(HEADERS):

```
SRC=a.c b.c
OBJ=a.o b.o
HEADERS=a.h b.h

all: lib.so

$(OBJ): $(SRC) $(HEADERS)
    cc -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -c $<

lib.so: $(OBJ)
    cc -shared $(OBJ) -o $@
```

Se possível gostaria que fosse 100% em make

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro o seguinte makefile:

```
SOURCES = a.c b.c

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

CFLAGS= -MMD -c -fpic

all: lib.so

-include $(OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)

%.o: %.c
    cc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

lib.so: $(OBJECTS)
    cc -shared $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

O utilizador precisa apenas de modificar a linha `SOURCES = a.c b.c` para acrescentar ou remover um ficheiro fonte (extensão .c).

A variável OBJECTS representa a lista dos ficheiros objeto relocalizáveis. Neste caso é equivalente a `a.o b.o` resultante da substituição da extensão .c por .o a partir da variável SOURCES.

A opção -MMD faz com que o compilador gere também um ficheiro com extensão .d contendo regras indicando as dependências do ficheiro objeto. Por exemplo:

```
a.o: a.c a.h
```

A diretiva `-include` incorpora no `makefile` as regras provenientes dos ficheiros .d que se acrescentam à regra implícita

```
%.o: %.c
    cc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

o que obriga à compilação caso haja alteração num ficheiro de *include* (extensão .h).

Ao primeiro processamento deste `makefile` não existem ficheiros .d. Como também não existem .o não representa problema -- a compilação seria sempre realizada. O hífen antes da palavra `include` serve para indicar ao `make` que neste caso deve prosseguir com o processamento.